# git fetching 'lost' commits

Tags: git, git-fetch, git-reflog

Short version: Is it possible to use 'git fetch' to get commits from a remote repo that are not visible in the git log (part of/under the HEAD commit)

Longer version:
I have a repo (remote copy) that looks like this:

```
A - B - C - D(HEAD)
         \
          \-E
```

The remote version got to this state by making commit E, resetting to commit C, then making commit D.

Locally, I have an old clone of that repo that looks like this:

```
A - B - C(HEAD)
```

When I fetch from the remote repo, I only get commit D, but I would like to be able to reset --hard to commit E in my local repo.

Comment: What happens when you try to `git fetch` an explicit commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some background first so that it's clearer what I mean below:  The `fetch` command works in two parts, one on your end (you run `git fetch`) and one on the remote (the remote gets the incoming request over `http://`, `git://`, `ssh://`, or some other protocol and fires up something, usually the internal `git upload-pack` program).  The upload-pack step, which runs on the remote, makes a series of *offers* of the form "I have an object" (typically a commit or annotated tag) "with ID *id* of type *type* named *name*".

You can see what the remote will *offer* by running `git ls-remote` instead of `git fetch`.  This still runs `upload-pack` but instead of retrieving what is offered, it just shows (lists) the offers.

Whatever you see here in the offer list is what you can get.  If it does not show up here, you cannot get it—or at least, not through `git fetch`.  Some other methods, including `git archive`, may allow you to access commits by their raw SHA-1s, if you know them.

#### Making it fetch-able

Given your description, it sounds like the remote has reflogs turned on (is a regular, non-bare repository).  Commit `E` used to be on some branch (and at `HEAD`) but has been reset away so that it is only accessible through the two reflogs for `HEAD` and the branch.

Normally<sup>1</sup> `upload-pack` offers `HEAD` plus all refs in `refs`.  Reflogs are *not* in `refs` so `upload-pack` does not offer them.  This means that if there is no current ref pointing to your commit `E` it will not be offered.  To get it to be offered, log in to the remote and create a ref pointing to commit `E`, and then it will.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is somewhat configurable; see [`git-namespaces`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitnamespaces.html) and the three `hideRefs` configuration items in [`git-config`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html).

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Do a `git fetch --all` and you will get all the commits.

The checkout the desired commit and that it.

```
git fetch --all --prune
git checkout <SHA_1>
```

Comment: I think `git fetch --all` just fetches from all remotes. @JohnGreth wants a commit that is not pointed to by any ref. I suspect that what @torek says is true.